# How to remove extra reference from Microsoft.AspNetCore.All Meta package

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an asp.net core 2.0 application it references package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` when I publish this without creating `TargetManifest` the publish size is around 40MB and it contains packages which are not used in the application is there any way to identify and remove the packages that are not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to identify and remove the packages that are not used

Nope, cuz it's metapackage in nuget. To achieve that point i suggest to pick manually packages what you need and add to project replacing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`

List of all included packages you can find on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/) in `Dependencies` section