# How to remove reference to unused assembly inside Dependencies/Frameworks/Microsoft.NETCore.App?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-6.0

There're assemblies inside .NET 6 framework which I'm 100% sure I'll never use, however they still appear in the list of dependencies, ReSharper (and likely bare VS as well) still suggests them when importing types, and  in general their existence is annoying.

[image]

For example, I'm 100% sure I'll never use `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` or `System.Drawing`, yet when writing `Color` I see IDE suggesting types I can't really use. I'm abandoning my Windows-only ways and I want to never see these again.

I tried pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> after selecting the node, nothing happened. I tried adding `<Reference Remove="System.Drawing" />` to my .csproj file, nothing happened. I tried using "Remove unused references", nothing happened.

**Question:** Is there any way to get rid of these references? Removing them from the list would be perfect, but just hiding them from suggestions of VS/R# would be fine too.

I've found multiple questions regarding removing references on SO, but they all seem to be about .NET 4.x, about adding an alternative, all this not being useful for my case.

VS2022 17.0.1, R# 2021.3 EAP, .NET 6.0, latest everything.

Comment: What is your `TargetFramework` ?

Comment: @GuruStron `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: You'd need to create a custom SDK definition. One that imports just what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178624/736079

Comment: @jessehouwing Any directions with this approach? I see `System.Drawing` being mentioned only in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop.WindowsForms.props` and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets`, both seem to apply only in WinForms and .NETFramework cases. `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is mentioned only in `Microsoft.NET.DefaultPackageConflictOverrides.targets`, which I assume is used for removing NuGet references for newer .NET Core versions. How can I remove something with a custom SDK when it isn't included in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

These assemblies are called `MetaPackages` and you can't delete them. This is a similar question that may help you :
[How to remove extra reference from Microsoft.AspNetCore.All Meta package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256950/how-to-remove-extra-reference-from-microsoft-aspnetcore-all-meta-package)

Comment: This seems to apply to older .NET Core versions where all these packages actually existed as separate entities in the form of NuGet packages and were copied next to my compiled files. I don't see any of this happening now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove it there, but after your project is built you can "treeshake" all unused parts with some tools. Most obfuscators have a function for that purpose and I believe <strike>ILMerge also has a switch to trim unused types</strike> (Edit: [no it does not](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge/issues/61)).

Note that if you use reflection allot, you risk getting TypeLoadException's when types are removed that have no static reference but are always loaded dynamically through reflection. Using the attribute [ObfuscationAttribute(Exclude=true)] from these classes may help but actually the attribute has no specific property to prevent the class from being removed (only the attribute itself). Specific obfuscators will have their own options or features to prevent pruning.

In .Net 6 you can use Visual Studio to publish your project to a folder, choose self-contained and in the file publishing options you will find "produce single file". This will try to prune any unused (framework) assemblies. It will not prune unused classes in used assemblies.

If you want to prevent the unwanted options to show up in Intellisense, I guess you are out of luck. You could use an older version of visual studio that would only show items available in the defined scope (referenced in the project and in the `using` list of your `namespace` or `class`). I personally find the newer intellisense suggestions helpful, it saves me looking up the namespace and assembly name when I only remember the classname.